# I'm trying to make parallax effect on scroll but for the items to move the opposite way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have a students section coming down when scrolling down from underneath my header which has a video as a banner as well, so I need that section to scroll down from underneath that video using parallax on scroll effect.

This is what I've tried already but it just moves up when I scroll down like other parallax effects :

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  $('.section__students').css({
    'transform': 'translateY(-' + wScroll / 9 + '%)'
  });
});
```

```css
.students-main {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel__button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  transform: translateY(-45%);
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
}

.carousel__button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.carousel__button--left {
  left: 3.5rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.carousel__button--right {
  right: 3.5rem;
}

.arrow-left-students {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.arrow-left-students:hover {
  color: $color-primary;
}

.arrow-right-students {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.arrow-right-students:hover {
  color: $color-primary;
}

.carousel__nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 3rem 0;
}

.carousel__indicator {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1.6rem;
  height: 1.6rem;
  background: $color-gray-dark-2;
  margin: 0 1.2rem;
}

.carousel__indicator:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

section .students-h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -140px);
}

.students-h1::after {
  content: '';
  width: 10rem;
  height: .8rem;
  background-color: $color-primary-light;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -24rem;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 30px);
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.wrap-students {
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 3rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 30rem;
  width: 30rem;
  background-color: $color-grey-light-1;
  border-radius: 3rem;
}

.wrap-students:hover {
  box-shadow: -1px 3px 20px 3px $color-primary-light;
  transform: translateY(-10%);
  transition: all .5s;
}

.students {
  padding: 2.5rem 6rem;
}

.students .students-name {
  color: $color-gray-dark-2;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.students .students-description {
  margin-top: .5rem;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.wrap-students .students .students-img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 16rem;
  height: 16rem;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="rellax section__students students-main" data-rellax-speed="7">
  <div class="carousel">
    <button class="carousel__button carousel__button--left">
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-left arrow-left-students"></i>
    </button>
    <h1 class="students-h1">Students</h1>
    <div class="wrap-students">
      <div class="students" data-rellax-speed="8">
        <img class="students-img" src="/img/student1.jpg" alt="student-image">
        <h2 class="students-name">Nick Harrison</h2>
        <p class="students-description">lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-students">
      <div class="students">
        <img class="students-img" src="/img/student3.jpg" alt="student-image">
        <h2 class="students-name">Nick Harrison</h2>
        <p class="students-description">lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-students">
      <div class="students" data-rellax-speed="8">
        <img class="students-img" src="/img/student1.jpg" alt="student-image">
        <h2 class="students-name">Nick Harrison</h2>
        <p class="students-description">lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-students">
      <div class="students">
        <img class="students-img" src="/img/student3.jpg" alt="student-image">
        <h2 class="students-name">Nick Harrison</h2>
        <p class="students-description">lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel__button carousel__button--right">
     <i class="fas fa-chevron-right arrow-right-students"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="carousel__nav">
      <button class="carousel__indicator"></button>
      <button class="carousel__indicator"></button>
      <button class="carousel__indicator"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I just added my html and css too

Comment: can you clarify more what is the section do you want to make it a parallax? I tried to test your code to check where is the section but I didn't know, so can you explain to help you

Comment: In the section are some cards with rounded images of some students and they are like 4 cards

Answer (score 0):

if you set a negative number to the `Y` axis, it will go up. Try removing the `-` in

```
    $('.section__students').css({
      'transform': 'translateY(' + wScroll / 9 + '%)'
    });
```

Or setting a greater value than the actual. I see that students have `-50%`, try setting only greater values e.g. `-30%`  else it will keep going up.

Comment: Yeah, I did that first time, but do I also have to position the section higher to make the effect that I want? I'm trying to get the section scroll down from underneath my video banner from my header!

Comment: have you tried setting greater values than the actual? can you share a better code snippet example?

Comment: I have tried with 12 instead of 9 ... but still nothing , do I have to change the starting position in my css/scss file ? for my cards section? so they could scroll down from underneath my Video ?

Comment: Bro, you can also leave all that way, and declare an int variable that will decrement its value while scrolling. No need to divide the scrollTop value by 9 or 12. But only need to check the scroll direction with "event.originalEvent.wheelDelta", if its possitive, is going up, else, going down, and increment or decrement the var value.

Comment: can you write that down for me please, cause I'm new to javascript and i don't really know too much about it ..., thank you, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

firstly at Parallex, you don't need javascript to do it, so you can eliminate the script tag

from your comment, I think you need to make the parallax at each image in the 4 cards so you can add the following code

```
<style>
.parallax {
        /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 16rem;
        height: 16rem;
        object-fit: cover;
        object-position: 50% 10%;
    }
    .parallax1{
        /* The image used */
        background-image: url("img/img4.png"); // you can add your image here this is an example
    }
</style>

at HTML
 <h1 class="students-h1">Students</h1>
        <div class="wrap-students"> 
            <div class="students" data-rellax-speed="8">
                <div class="parallax1 parallax"></div> // this div is instead of the img tag
                <h2 class="students-name">Nick Harrison</h2>
                <p class="students-description">lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Yeah but I don't have an image background in my project, I have a Video as a banner in my Header, and all of those cards I need them to get out when I scroll down from underneath that Video..., but Thankyou anyway, I appreciate.

Comment: aha, ok you can just change the image-back at CSS to video URL in the background, good luck